# Casting of a custom class cell for UIViewTable fails with optional unwrap error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I got UITableView with two types of cells. The first type presents existing data, the second is used to add new items to the table. So I created a subclass "AddListTableViewCell" and put in "@IBOutlet weak var addListTextBox: UITextField!" property to read it's contents.
This "Add List" cell was drawn in the first row with no runtime errors. It was pushed by:

```
@IBAction func AddListButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if !isAddingList {
        isAddingList = true
        ListsTableView.reloadData()
        let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as? AddListTableViewCell
        cell.addListTextBox.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

On ListsTableView.reloadData() method "tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" has created additional cell. Again: no errors.

Then I changed it's order wishing it to be presented at the end of the table and added more demo items to observe it's interaction (forRow in AddListButtonPressed changed too :).

Now when I ran the app and pressed AddListButton, that fires func AddListButtonPressed, I got "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" with "let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as? AddListTableViewCell".

Futhermore, if view was scrolled after the app starts, there are no errors, but warnig "[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on > without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring." in the console.

I found a solution on this site to replace faulty line 
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as? AddListTableViewCell
with 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddList", forIndexPath: path) as! AddListTableViewCell
and it works well but I still generates a warning.

But why am I supposed to create cell again, when it's already set with "tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" method upon "ListsTableView.reloadData()"? Is it possible to somehow keep "let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as? AddListTableViewCell" to avoid warnings?

**EDIT** One more function, where it's used (sorry for no indention, posted from phone):

```
private func addList () {
    let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: brain.tree.count, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path) as! AddListTableViewCell
    if let listName = cell.addListTextBox.text {
        if listName.characters.filter({!" ".characters.contains($0)}).count > 0 {
            brain.newList(listName)
            cell.addListTextBox.text = ""
            isAddingList = false
            ListsTableView?.reloadData()
            performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowTasksSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The cellForRowAtIndexPath tableview method may return nil if the requested index path isn't on screen.  I would suggest that you scroll the tableview to the bottom and reload the last row, then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath data source method you can render the cell appropriately for add mode

Comment: tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath shows the cell perfectly after the render, still I can not cast it due to error and therefore access it's property :(

Comment: Please edit your question show the code you have - you shouldn't need to access the cell outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Paulw11 please, how should I access it's stored value without accessing the cell? By protocol? This cell has single textbox respresented by an outlet in AddListTableViewCell class. And I need to get user input from this textbox somehow, I need this textbox to become first responder etc. What can I do outside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Posted other function to show how I'm trying to abuse cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Perhaps an alternative approach would be to have the user tap the "add" row rather than a separate button - that way you know that the cell is on screen

Comment: Are you using addList to add a new row to the tableView that wasn't there before? It doesn't work that way. First you tell the tableView that you want a new row (without content). Then you get asked for the content in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: No, it just called Add List, because it creates a new list (of tasks). Name of this list is to be received from textBox in a cell : AddListTableViewCell. The cell itself is created when isAddingList : Bool is true in cellForRowAtIndexPath: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AddListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddListTableViewCell` & `return cell`